# Why mocking private field is bad?

Tags: java

Let's say I have some class A whith inner dependency to class B, which is initialized in private field:

```
class SomeSpecialProcessing {
    private BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
    // some other fields

    public SomeSpecialProcessing() {
        this.bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("something.log"));
    }

    public String doSomeProcessing() {
        // some special calculation 
        persistToDisc(somethingImportant);
        // some special processing
        return importantResult;
    }

    private void persistToDisc(String somethingImportant) {
        // this.bufferedWriter.write(str);
    }
}
```

Now I need to create Unit test for public method doSomeProcessing() but I don't want to write anything to disc as it is time consuming operation. Therefore I have to mock **bufferedWriter**.

Now I have 2 possibilities how to do that:

1. Allow to class **SomeSpecialProcessing** to set **bufferedWriter** externally with setter or constructor and then in Unit test I will pass mock into this field.
2. In Unit test I will mock **bufferedWriter** using **reflection**.

Now I prefer using **reflection** but lot of people say it's bad practise and will recommend to add **bufferedWriter** into constructor or into setter. But I think it's stupid to exposure internal fields of class **just because** of Unit tests.

How to resolve this kind of problem?

Comment: Exposing which file you are writing to is probably better than hard coding it and it will make it easier to test.

Comment: You would not like to get your constructor fail with en exception. Initializing BufferedWriter there is a wrong place.

Comment: You could think about following the [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), it would make this much more testable. You've coupled `SomeSpecialProcessing` too tightly to the specific `BufferedWriter` and `FileWriter`.

Comment: If you follow Dependency inversion principal, your next question is probably going to be, "How do I then manage all my dependencies?"

1. Factories everywhere. 2. Dependency Injection Frameworks.

But it does allow you to reuse code effectively.

Comment: If you are thinking, "What about the encapsulation of special processing" Well, code reuse / DI would say, "What about when you want to dump a copy as a debug, or run 2 side by side just to see what happens." Then you would need an additional log.

Comment: This also appears to be about logging, Logging is largely a solved problem, by many different frameworks, If you want your users to have the flexibility they need, to be alerted by errors, then looking into a real logging framework is going to save you a ton of boilerplate and configuration for any sufficiently advanced logging scenario.

Comment: I know Dependency inversion as I'm often programming in Spring Framework. But I just want to resolve this problem without such framework. Isn't it stupid to use DI only because somebody will say that using reflection in Unit test is bad? I will just use reflection and entire problem is solved.

Comment: @Jurass Dependency inversion is a principle. Dependency injection frameworks are a tool you can use to follow that principle. You can practice dependency inversion without any framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I think it's stupid to exposure internal fields of class just
>   because of Unit tests

It's doesn't just make your code easier to unit test, it makes your code more flexible in general.

Currently you have a very inflexible class. It can do some processing and persist to a single file called `something.log`. It writes it in a very specific way (using a `BufferedWriter`) which may or may not be the most efficient way to write that particular output. Basically, you are taking control away from your class's users.

By generalising your dependency to *anything which can write a string somewhere*, you increase the flexibility of your class and allow its users to make their own decisions about what are the best dependencies to provide to suit their requirements.

```
class SomeSpecialProcessing {
    private Writer writer;

    public SomeSpecialProcessing(Writer writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public String doSomeProcessing() {
        // some special calculation 
        persist(somethingImportant);
        // some special processing
        return importantResult;
    }

    private void persist(String somethingImportant) {
        this.writer.write(str);
    }
}
```

You already have 2 use-cases for your class: write to an actual log, and do nothing. You already, to an extent, *require* that flexibility. You want to side-step this by using reflection, claiming that it's just as good.

The problem is that it's not just as good. Reflection-based tests are going to be significantly more brittle. Feel like refactoring the name of the private field? Oh look, I've broken my test. Feel like changing the internal implementation to not use a `BufferedWriter`? Oh look, I've broken my test.

Comment: Well I have nothing against your solution, but when I write classes I just want blackboxes with simple as possible interface - only something which its user really need. Why I should exposure some Writer? It's just internal thing of this class, persisting something in file for itself. Nobody should be interested why it is like that. With your solution I have to explain to user what Writer is and why there is possibility to set it. So basically your solution is "make it more flexible" but my problem is "I don't want to have it flexible".

Comment: @MichaelI know about this problems with refactoring. But.Let's say you will create such high flexible classes A, B, C and they will have to be connected in  some difficult way together to achieve some functionality F. Now you want to make interface to this functionality F because user of your functionality is not interesting in joining together manually some A, B, C, so you will create class F where this functionality can be called by single one function. And you have back that problem here! F have inner dependency to A, B, C, where C is class to start autodestruction. How you will mocking C?

Comment: @Jurass if you want to claim *"the BufferedWriter is totally internal to SomeSpecialProcessing, nothing else should have to care about it and it will never change"* then fine, continue with your current implementation. But now note that the testing boundary also moves - your test should be opening `something.log` and making sure the right output got written to it. Otherwise you're mocking out part of the class under test.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, it will be exactly achieved with that mock! I will test if method bufferedWriter.write(something) has been called with preassumed argument.

Comment: @Jurass no, because you've made that part of the class, an implementation detail, by completely encapsulating it. There's really no point asking why if it's bad if you're going to dismiss everyone who tells you why and not change anything, just press on regardless.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If what did you say is true, therefore in general it means: "Every class instances internally used in some class A have to be instantiated outside of class A" or maybe softly "have to be instantiated outside of class A as much as possible". I have never ever read such rule for OOP.